# Using an output escaped element in another part of the XSL

Tags: xslt

I can't figure out how to save an output escaped element which contains an XML table and do transformations on that XML table. I cant seem to access the nodes of the escaped element.

This is the XML:

```
<TABEL_HUIDIGE_SITUATIE>&lt;ELEMNEW_TABEL Type=&quot;4912&quot;&gt;&lt;Table&gt;&lt;TableRow RowId=&quot;0&quot;&gt;&lt;TC Bold=&quot;true&quot;&gt;Nr.&lt;/TC&gt;&lt;TC Bold=&quot;true&quot;&gt;Omschrijving&lt;/TC&gt;&lt;TC Bold=&quot;true&quot;&gt;Bedrag&lt;/TC&gt;&lt;TC Bold=&quot;true&quot;&gt;BTW-productboekingsgroep&lt;/TC&gt;&lt;TC Bold=&quot;true&quot;&gt;Bedrag Incl BTW&lt;/TC&gt;&lt;/TableRow&gt;&lt;TableRow RowId=&quot;1&quot;&gt;&lt;TC Type=&quot;31488&quot;&gt;010&lt;/TC&gt;&lt;TC Type=&quot;31488&quot;&gt;Antenne BTW&lt;/TC&gt;&lt;TC Type=&quot;12799&quot;&gt;12.021,55&lt;/TC&gt;&lt;TC Type=&quot;31489&quot;&gt;21% INT&lt;/TC&gt;&lt;TC Type=&quot;31488&quot;&gt;14.546,08&lt;/TC&gt;&lt;/TableRow&gt;&lt;/Table&gt;&lt;/ELEMNEW_TABEL&gt;
</TABEL_HUIDIGE_SITUATIE>
```

The unescaped XML will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ELEMNEW_TABEL Type="4912"><Table><TableRow RowId="0"><TC Bold="true">Nr.</TC><TC Bold="true">Omschrijving</TC><TC Bold="true">Bedrag</TC><TC Bold="true">BTW-productboekingsgroep</TC><TC Bold="true">Bedrag Incl BTW</TC></TableRow><TableRow RowId="1"><TC Type="31488">010</TC><TC Type="31488">Antenne BTW</TC><TC Type="12799">12.021,55</TC><TC Type="31489">21% INT</TC><TC Type="31488">14.546,08</TC></TableRow></Table></ELEMNEW_TABEL>
```

This is the XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="exsl">

<xsl:template name="box2">
  <xsl:param name="rtf"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($rtf)/node()" mode="doe"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" mode="doe">
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="doe">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="box2">
      <xsl:with-param name="rtf">
 <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

I dont know if the output escaped content is recognized as XML or a string. I cant use xpath within <xsl:value-of select="." />.  I've read like 50 stackoverflow topics but I can't seem to get it to work. How can I save the output escaped xml so that I can transform the TC nodes? Does anyone have a suggestion? Thanks!

Tried different approaches to access the nodes but with no result.

Comment: Two pass transform? Have a secondary XSLT transform the output of your current transform (since disable-output-escape is serialization hint, it won't be "seen" as XML until it has been read in AS XML).

Comment: Thanks. I really hoped there would be a function to transform it to a node-set.

Comment: Remember that the reason for escaping `<` as `&lt;` is to tell the XML parser: this isn't markup, this is ordinary plain text. By escaping it, you're telling the parser to treat it as text, not as markup. So it's not surprising that you can't then query it as if it were markup. The way to convert text-containing-angle-brackets to a node tree is to parse it, which can be done in XSLT 3.0 using the `parse-xml()` function, and in earlier versions using extension functions if available in your chosen processor.

Answer (score 1):

With XSLT 3.0 you have the [`parse-xml()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-parse-xml) function, which will return the parsed XML that you can use XPath against within your XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the answer already given, in XSLT 3 (the current version of XSLT since 2017) you have functions `parse-xml` and `parse-xml-fragment` so there you can do e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="TABEL_HUIDIGE_SITUATIE">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="parse-xml(.)/node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="TC">
    ..
  </xsl:template>
```

[Online sample](https://martin-honnen.github.io/cheerpj3-saxonhe12-fiddle/?code=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0A%20%20expand-text%3D%22yes%22%3E%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22TABEL_HUIDIGE_SITUATIE%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acopy%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22parse-xml%28.%29%2Fnode%28%29%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Acopy%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22TC%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amessage%3EProcessed%20%7Bnode-name%28%29%7D%3C%2Fxsl%3Amessage%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Anext-match%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22xml%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%20name%3D%22xsl%3Ainitial-template%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acopy%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acomment%3ERun%20with%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27xsl%3Aproduct-name%27%29%7D%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27xsl%3Aproduct-version%27%29%7D%20at%20%7Bcurrent-dateTime%28%29%7D%3C%2Fxsl%3Acomment%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Acopy%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0A&input=%3CTABEL_HUIDIGE_SITUATIE%3E%26lt%3BELEMNEW_TABEL%20Type%3D%26quot%3B4912%26quot%3B%26gt%3B%26lt%3BTable%26gt%3B%26lt%3BTableRow%20RowId%3D%26quot%3B0%26quot%3B%26gt%3B%26lt%3BTC%20Bold%3D%26quot%3Btrue%26quot%3B%26gt%3BNr.%26lt%3B%2FTC%26gt%3B%26lt%3BTC%20Bold%3D%26quot%3Btrue%26quot%3B%26gt%3BOmschrijving%26lt%3B%2FTC%26gt%3B%26lt%3BTC%20Bold%3D%26quot%3Btrue%26quot%3B%26gt%3BBedrag%26lt%3B%2FTC%26gt%3B%26lt%3BTC%20Bold%3D%26quot%3Btrue%26quot%3B%26gt%3BBTW-productboekingsgroep%26lt%3B%2FTC%26gt%3B%26lt%3BTC%20Bold%3D%26quot%3Btrue%26quot%3B%26gt%3BBedrag%20Incl%20BTW%26lt%3B%2FTC%26gt%3B%26lt%3B%2FTableRow%26gt%3B%26lt%3BTableRow%20RowId%3D%26quot%3B1%26quot%3B%26gt%3B%26lt%3BTC%20Type%3D%26quot%3B31488%26quot%3B%26gt%3B010%26lt%3B%2FTC%26gt%3B%26lt%3BTC%20Type%3D%26quot%3B31488%26quot%3B%26gt%3BAntenne%20BTW%26lt%3B%2FTC%26gt%3B%26lt%3BTC%20Type%3D%26quot%3B12799%26quot%3B%26gt%3B12.021%2C55%26lt%3B%2FTC%26gt%3B%26lt%3BTC%20Type%3D%26quot%3B31489%26quot%3B%26gt%3B21%25%20INT%26lt%3B%2FTC%26gt%3B%26lt%3BTC%20Type%3D%26quot%3B31488%26quot%3B%26gt%3B14.546%2C08%26lt%3B%2FTC%26gt%3B%26lt%3B%2FTableRow%26gt%3B%26lt%3B%2FTable%26gt%3B%26lt%3B%2FELEMNEW_TABEL%26gt%3B%0D%0A%3C%2FTABEL_HUIDIGE_SITUATIE%3E&code-type=XSLT&input-type=XML).

Comment: Thank you very much. I did try parse-xml but it didnt work because I wasnt on version 3. I will ask our vendor if its possible to update to version 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you are limited to XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, you need to start with:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="TABEL_HUIDIGE_SITUATIE" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and save the result to a file. Then you can apply a secondary transformation, using another stylesheet, to the saved file.

Without this, you would need to parse the input using string functions - which would be very laborious and error-prone.

---

P.S. If your data provider wants you to read (and process) the contents as XML, then they should not escape it.

Comment: Depending on which XSLT 1 or 2 processor you use and how you use it, it might be possible to use extension functions, e.g. for libxslt from Python https://lxml.de/extensions.html or PHP or for MSXML from JScript or for XslCompiledTransform from a .NET language, as long as you can write additional code, it is possible to call into (depending on the processor) e.g. Python or PHP or JScript or a .NET language to parse the XML string.

Comment: Thank you. This will be our backup option if its not possible to update to version 3. The xml is returned from an ERP based on Microsoft Business Central. The escaped format was the only supported format from our vendor.